# Should Python class filenames also be camelCased?

Tags: python, naming-conventions, filenames, camelcasing

I know that classes in Python are typically cased using camelCase.

Is it also the normal convention to have the file that contains the class also be camelCase'd especially if the file only contains the class?

For example, should class `className` also be stored in `className.py` instead of `class_name.py`?

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/399583/304109

Comment: camels are animals and are not proper nouns and thus begin with a lower case letter as in camelCase. Pascal is a last name (surname) and is a proper noun and thus begins with an upper case letter as in PascalCase.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

The following answer is largely sourced from [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/308972/python-file-naming-convention).

If you're going to follow PEP 8, you should stick to all-lowercase names, with optional underscores.

To quote [PEP 8's naming conventions for packages & modules](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names):

> Modules should have short, all-lowercase names. Underscores can be used in the module name if it improves readability.

And for classes:

> Class names should normally use the CapWords convention.

See [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/111871/module-vs-package/111882#111882) for the difference between a module, class and package:

> A Python module is simply a Python source file, which can expose classes, functions and global variables.

Comment: Should the names use the singular or plural form though?

Comment: @guival I would argue singular, but there may be exceptions to that general rule. I don't know of anything as official as a PEP about plurality, but you can find other discussions of naming style best practices, like this one: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/75919/should-package-names-be-singular-or-plural

Answer (score 28):

The official convention is to use all lower case for file names (as others have already stated).  The reason, however, has not been mentioned...

Since Python works cross platform (and it is common to use it in that manner), but file systems vary in the use of casing, it is better to just eliminate alternate cases.  In Linux, for instance, it is possible to have MyClass.py and myclass.py in the same directory.  That is not so in Windows!

On a related note, if you have MyClass.py and myclass.py in a git repo, or even just change the casing on the same file, git can act funky when you push/pull across from Linux and Windows.

And, while barely on topic, but in the same vein, SQL has these same issues where different standards and configurations may or may not allow UpperCases on table names.

I, personally, find it more pleasant to read TitleCasing / camelCasing even on filenames, but when you do anything that can work cross platform it's safest not to.

Comment: How does making the filename all lowercase avoid you accidentally having a CapWords-style filename as well, in Linux? If the problem is that the OS allows filenames with different cases but same letters, then the solution is to be consistent with whatever naming convention you chose (all lower case, or CapWords-case), not to avoid uppercase altogether.

Comment: How does NOT "using all lowercase avoid you accidentally having a CapWords-style filename" conflict in Linux?  It doesn't.  You can create a problem of this sort either way if you aren't careful.  The official standard for Python, and for libraries I've seen in other cross platform languages is to use all lowercase.  I'm offering a practical explanation here for the reasoning which extends beyond preference.  Using all lowercase is *one* means for *mitigating* this issue.  I often fail to adhere to this "rule" myself, as I'm not keen on it.  On some rare occasions it has come back to bite me.

Answer (score 13):

> My question is, is it also the normal convention to have the file that
>   contains the class also be camelCase'd especially if the file only
>   contains the class

Short answer: No.

Longer answer: should be all lower case and underscores as needed.

From [PEP8 "Package and Module Names"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names):

> Modules should have short, all-lowercase names. Underscores can be
>   used in the module name if it improves readability. Python packages
>   should also have short, all-lowercase names, although the use of
>   underscores is discouraged.

If you're unclear what a [module](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) is:

> A module is a file containing Python definitions and statements. The
>   file name is the module name with the suffix .py appended.

Answer (score 12):

There is a difference in the naming convention of the class name and the file that contains this class. This missunderstanding might come from languages like java where it is common to have one file per class.

In python you can have several classes per modul (a simple .py file). The classes in this module/file should be called according to the class naming convention: Class names should normally use the CapWords convention.
The file containing this classes should follow the modul naming convention: Modules should have short, all-lowercase names. Underscores can be used in the module name if it improves readability.

=> CamelCase should in the file camelcase.py (or camel_case.py if neccessary)

Comment: I followed your reasoning until the last sentence. `CamelCase should in the file camelcase.py`, can you please clarify what you mean?

Comment: @MEMark He means, for class `CamelCase` use filename `camelcase.py`

Answer (score 6):

First of all, as mentioned above, class names should be CapWords, e.g.:

```py
class SampleClass:
   ...
```

**BEWARE:** Having the same name for file (module) and class creates confusions.

**Example 1:** Say you have the following module structure:

```
src/
   __init__.py
   SampleClass.py
main.py
```

Your `SampleClass.py` is:

```py
class SampleClass:
   ...
```

Your `main.py` is:

```py
from src import SampleClass

instance = SampleClass()
```

Will this code work? NO, cause you should've done either `from src.SampleClass import SampleClass` or `instance = SampleClass.SampleClass()`. Awkward code, isn't it?

You can also fix it by adding the following content to `__init__.py`:

```py
from .SampleClass import SampleClass
```

Which leads to the Example 2.

**Example 2:** Say you develop a module:

```
src/
   __init__.py
   BaseClass.py
   ConcreteClass.py
main.py
```

`BaseClass.py` content:

```py
class BaseClass:
    ...
```

`ConcreteClass.py` content:

```py
from src import BaseClass

class ConcreteClass(BaseClass):
    ...
```

And your `__init__.py` content:

```py
from .ConcreteClass import ConcreteClass
from .BaseClass import BaseClass
```

And `main.py` content is:

```py
from src import ConcreteClass

instance = ConcreteClass()
```

The code fails with an error:

```bash
    class ConcreteClass(BaseClass):
TypeError: module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

It took me a while to understand the error and why I cannot inherit from the class, cause in previous example when I added exports to `__init__.py` file everything worked. If you use snake case file names it does not fix the problem but the error is a bit easier to understand:

```bash
ImportError: cannot import name 'BaseClass' from partially initialized module 'src'
```

To fix the code you need to fix the import in `ConcreteClass.py` to be: `from .BaseClass import BaseClass`.

**Last caveat**, if in original code you would switch places imports in `__init__.py` so it looks like:

```
from .BaseClass import BaseClass
from .ConcreteClass import ConcreteClass
```

Initial code works, but you really don't want anyone to write a code that will depend on the order of imports. If someone changes the order or applies `isort` tool to organize imports, good luck fixing those bugs.

Comment: Thank you and a very nice explanation with details.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on what IDE you are using, the convention may change. I am using Visual Studio Code and the error I had said, `Module name "[file name]" doesn't conform to snake_case naming` . I am guessing snake_case means all lowercase with all spaces replaced with underscores. PEP 8 says to use all lowercase with occasional underscores if you want, but Vsc says to use all lowercase with all underscores. So I think it might depend.

Comment: It doesn't depend on IDE, it depends on standards that your project enforces. It's possible to tell IDEs toenforce different standards.